# Using a nucleo board as ST-link for STM32F722RET6 (Error: ST-LINK error (DEV_TARGET_CMD_ERR))

Tags: microcontroller, usb, stm32, nucleo, st-link

we have disconnected the ST-link from the nucleoboard and prepared it correctly for its use. we connected it back to the nucleoboard, and everything worked like it should.
We want to use this ST-link to make contact to the MCU of a flight controller that we have designed. the connection goes as follows:

ST-link:
 1. VDD
 2. SWCLK
 3. GND
 4. SWDIO
 5. NRST
 6. SWO

Flight controller:
 1. GND
 2. SWCLK
 3. SWDIO
 4. SWO
 5. NRST
 6. VDD

NRST goes to NRST, SWO to SWO etc.

When we connect the ST-link to STM32CubeProgrammer, the ST-link appears as a usb unit and we get contact with the program. we get an error though:
ST-LINK Firmware version : V2J29M18
Error: ST-LINK error (DEV_TARGET_CMD_ERR)

Does anyone have an idea whats wrong?

Comment: Which Nucleo board?  As I recall they are programmed for the specific processor on the Nucleo board and are not full ST-Link2 images.

Comment: The nucleoboard is: Nucleo-F767ZI

Comment: Have you tried using the [ST-Link Utility](http://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-link004.html)? Maybe it needs a firmware update, the latest for my is V2.J29.S7 - which seems higher than yours.

Comment: What is the STM32CubeProgrammer? I have never heart of it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77227/discussion-on-question-by-ole-halvor-using-a-nucleo-board-as-st-link-for-stm32f7).